# Use list comprehension to calculate Net Present Value and Internal Rate of Return from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I downloaded a CSV file whose dataframe looks like this:

| Year 1 | Year 2 | Year 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -500 (Initial Investment) | -500 (Initial Investment) | -500 (Initial Investment) |
| 1000 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 1000 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 1000 | 1000 | 1000 |

I want to use list comprehension to create a new dataframe that would return the Net Present Value of the investment and the Internal Rate of Return. Both of these functions are available from Numpys and would simply be a result of "x" risk free rate and selecting the values of each column. np.npv(rf, values_year1). Ideally, I could insert any number of years and it would give me a dataframe with the corresponding values of each year, regardless of how many years I plug into the csv file. My new dataframe would look like this:

| Indicator | Year 1 | Year 2 | Year 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NPV | 5000 USD | 25000 USD | 25000 USD |
| IRR | 12% | 25% | 25% |

I know how to do this manually by just selecting each column and doing the calculations, but I really want to learn how to use list comprehension. Is it even possible to do this with list comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this gives you some help:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Year 1": [-500, 1000, 1000, 1000],"Year 2": [-500, 1000, 1000, 1000],"Year 3": [-500, 1000, 1000, 1000]})

def sumarize_ser(col):
    s =  col.agg(sum)
    return s

df2 = df.apply(sumarize_ser).to_frame()

s_values = df2[0].sum()

def calc_irr(line):
    return line/s_values*100

df2["IRR"] = df2[0].apply(calc_irr)

df2.T

Out[]:
    Year 1  Year 2  Year 3
0   2500.00 2500.00 2500.00
IRR 33.33   33.33   33.33
```